# How can I configure Elastic Beanstalk to show me only the relevant log file(s)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm an application developer with very limited knowledge of infrastructure. At my last job we frequently deployed Java web services (built as WAR files) to Elastic Beanstalk, and much of the infrastructure had already been set up before I ever started there, so I got to focus primarily on the code and not how things were tied together. One feature of Elastic Beanstalk that often came in handy was the button to "Request Logs," where you can select either the "Last 100 Lines" or the "Full Logs." What I'm used to seeing when clicking this button is to directly view the logs generated by my web service.

Now, at the new job, the infrastructure requirements are a little different, as we have to Dockerize everything before deploying it. I've been trying to stand up a Spring Boot web app inside a Docker container in Elastic Beanstalk, and have been running into trouble with that. And I also noticed a bizarre difference in behavior when I went to "Request Logs." Now when I choose one of those options, instead of dropping me into the relevant log file directly, it downloads a ZIP file containing the entire `/var/log` directory, with quite a number of disparate and irrelevant log files in there. I understand that there's no way for Amazon to know, necessarily, that I don't care about X log file but do care about Y log file, but was surprised that the behavior is different from what I was used to. I'm assuming this means the EB configuration at the last job was set up in a specific way to filter the one relevant log file, or something like that.

Is there some way to configure an Elastic Beanstalk application to only return one specific log file when you "Request Logs," rather than a ZIP file of the `/var/log` directory? Is this done with ebextensions or something like that? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too sure about the Beanstalk console, but using the EBCLI, if you enable CloudWatch log streaming (note that this would cost you to store logs in CloudWatch) for your Beanstalk instances, you can perform:

```
eb logs --stream --log-group <CloudWatch logGroup name>
```

The above command basically gives you the logs for your instance specific to the file/log group you specified. In order for the above command to work, you need to enable CloudWatch log streaming:

```
eb logs --stream enable
```

As an aside, to determine which log groups your environment presently has, perform:

```
aws logs describe-log-groups --region <region> | grep <beanstalk environment name>
```

Comment: That was it! Enabling Log Streaming changed the behavior of the Request Logs button.

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped.